# Heroku / Node - how to add git commit on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku

I'm learning Node and Git and I have a Heroku app that is reading and writing to a local file on the server (a very simple JSON database).

If I add the file to my gitignore locally, it disappears from my Heroku app and causes the app to error. But if I don't add it to my gitignore, it overwrites the latest version (on the server) with an old one I have locally.

Obviously the issue is because the changes on the server file aren't being committed. However, I don't know how to do that remotely, or if it's even possible. I can run heroku git:clone locally, but I can't run heroku:git add.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not commit a file that will be modified by the server.
It seems not a good idea because, as you said, this file will be overwrited by next push.

Usually you do not want to commit from your deployment branch, so it is not a good idea either to use *git* from server (and I doubt you can with Heroku).

Instead you could make your app check if the file exists and if not create that file on server.

That will work in a dedicated server you manage yourself, but Heroku doesn't work the same. Each push you make to your Heroku repository will in fact bundle your application before launching it on a dyno, and this process overwrite all the file, including your database JSON file, which will be no more persistent.

So I think you have no choice than switch to another storage method, for exemple subscribe a free Heroku *postgreSQL* plan or another database you prefer.